# How to troubleshoot missing sounds?

Tags: cyanogenmod, audio, troubleshooting

I have a strange problem with my Droid 4: sometimes it stops playing sounds (or music, or ringtones), and I can't figure out if there's something in particular that triggers this. The only fix I could find is rebooting the phone. What could I try to diagnose the problem?

(I'm using a Verizon-branded Droid 4 with Cyanogenmod 10.1.3, but I had the problem on 10.1.2 too. If it's relevant, I had to install "Tobby's mod" to enable GSM - I'm in Europe)

Comment: Have you checked your sound settings in those cases? From time to time, I encounter a similar strange issue, and find something has turned the volumes down or triggered mute. Happens very rarely to me, and usually only when there's no time to investigate, so I still don't know the source of that.

Comment: @Izzy: yes I've checked, but everything looks fine... It seems that the whole sound "subsystem" shuts down somehow... Maybe there's a way to reset that instead of the whole phone?

Comment: Might be. Several (most? all?) devices support a kind of "fast reboot", which is not really a reboot (in fact, it's the system server being restarted, see [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575): it's skipping the first 4 steps, and thus just runs the last 2 of system initialization). Corresponding apps require root (no prob for you according to your tags), see e.g. [Quick Boot (Reboot)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.siriusapplications.quickboot).

Comment: I'll try that and update my question with the results, thanks :) Maybe it'll help to shed some light on the problem itself