# GSM signal lost - howto get signal back without restarting

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, network-signal, gsm

Several times a week I have the problems where the GSM signal is lost on my phone, due to bad coverage in that area. The real problem for me is that when that happens, and when I move to a place with known coverage, the signal doesn't come back. The only solution I know is to restart the phone. Switching to airplane mode and back doesn't help.

Is there an app or method I can use to avoid the restart?

- Phone: Samsung Galaxy S2
- Android: Jelly Bean 4.2 (Avatarrom)

Comment: Until a real solution is found: you might wish to take a look at apps like [Quick Boot](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-boot-%28reboot%29/com.siriusapplications.quickboot). They avoid a complete reboot by restarting the system server, which is much faster as most of the boot-steps are skipped (5 of 7, to be more precise, see [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575)).

Comment: Thanks for the quick boot tip. I've installed it and will see how it works out.

Comment: If you add your comment as answer, I'll reward that.

Comment: Done. Better a work-around than nothing. Still keeping my fingers crossed for a "real solution" to the underlying issue; maybe a future update to your ROM will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is no complete solution, but at least a work-around, avoiding a long reboot:

There are apps like [Quick Boot](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-boot-%28reboot%29/com.siriusapplications.quickboot) (others have things like "fast reboot" and the like in their names/descriptions). Other suggested by those names, they do not really reboot your device, but simply restart the system server (for details, please take a look at [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575) – the system server is started at step 5 of 6 boot steps, so this skips more than half of the way down and up, effectively resulting in a process about 3 times as fast as a complete reboot).

While this way all your apps are killed as a side effect (as they require the system server to work), it's still a lot faster than a real reboot, and thus "less hazzle".