# How can I make persistent changes in root directory (/)?

Tags: file-system, mount, partitions

I have to edit my fstab in android 4.4 but the root is mounted in read only.
I've try to remount the root with
`mount -o rw,remount /`And I can edit the root files but when I reboot the device the changes disappear. 
How can I make persistent changes in / without rebuild the kernel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any changes to files in root directory (/) are gone after reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56888/any-changes-to-files-in-root-directory-are-gone-after-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

For that you'd need to edit the corresponding image (see [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd)), which is unpacked on each boot.

Alternatively, you could create a script replacing the `fstab` file, and have this run on each boot e.g. using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) or a similar app that can execute "stuff" automatically after boot.