# How do I make permanent changes to files in root (/) directory?

Tags: file-system, mount, partitions

Every time I edit a file in /, /sbin, or /system/bin it overwrites on restart (device is rooted and in r/w mode). I assume this is because Android mounts a temporary root? Or maybe it's just a problem on my device?

How do I make a permanent change to root files? Can I do this through adb? Do I need to edit the system image, and if so can anyone point me in the right direction on where to start on this?

Comment: Give us the details of the whole list of instructions you used to edit a file in /system/bin. As for files in `/` and `/sbin` - they are loaded from the kernel on every boot, so it's not worth editing them out if you intend to make changes persist across reboots. What device are you using?

Comment: I'm using a rooted LG G Pad 7.0 running 4.4.2. To accomplish what I want, I think I can get away with either replacing /sbin/chargerlogo with a copy of /system/bin/reboot, or replacing the contents of /sbin/chargerlogo with
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
However it needs to survive a reboot or it is not of any use. As for list of instructions... I was trying to do it through ES File Explorer with root explorer on, system in r/w mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any changes to files in root directory (/) are gone after reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56888/any-changes-to-files-in-root-directory-are-gone-after-reboot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root file system (`/`) and the files therein (plus several more in some sub-directories) are overwritten at boot time from the so-called [InitRd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) ("initial RAM disk", or "boot image"). So if you must change/add stuff there, you will have to modify that image.

If you just want to store some additional binaries/scripts, you should rather do so in **`/system/xbin`** (which usually is also contained in the `$PATH`) – though files in `/system/bin` should survive a reboot as well (`/system` is a separate partition usually mounted read-only, and thus not touched except for OS updates).

Comment: OP says he modifies `/system/bin` and it gets restored.

Comment: @SarpSTA I've read that – and somehow (at least partly) doubt it. As to my knowledge, neither shutdown nor boot tamper with `/system` except to (un)mount the partition (read-only that is). Not sure what's behind that. I've done such manipulations several times on different devices – so I'm pretty sure what sticks and what does not. Though I admit different devices/ROMs might have specifics I've not yet encountered – thinking e.g. of those always replacing `/recovery` with stock when flashed with something else, as I've read.

Comment: @SarpSTA It might not, sorry for the mistake. The files I want to edit are in / and /sbin, the file I want to copy is in /system/bin, so my bad on that. Izzy, thank you for this! Any resources to point in the right direction to modifying the InitRd?

Comment: @Alan Sorry, *that's* the part I didn't do yet (modifying the InitRd myself). I've *replaced* it sometimes, but the replacement was built by someone else. As this would be off-topic here anyway, I'd recommend [checking these posts at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=modify%20android%20boot%20image) :)

Comment: Anytime, Alan. A quick Google search just found this little tutorial: [Android boot.img manipulation](http://k.japko.eu/boot-img-manipulation.html) – which should answer your previous comment.