# Does all root directory in android os exist in flashing firmware

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, operating-system

At the root directory of android os there is some folder such as **/acct** **/root** **/sys** **/dev** , ... that are not available in firmware structure. by using fastboot to flash firmware There is some mount point like **/system** **/cust** **/recovery** **/boot** but there is no (/) root mount point.
I want to flash whole OS. Is there any firmware that contains above directories such as (/) root?
or how can i restore my hole android to factory snapshot?
My phone is huawei g6-u10.

Comment: Aside from `/system` and `/data`, most directories are generated dynamically at boot time, hence you don't see them in firmwares.

Comment: @AndyYan you could make that an answer, with some pointers on the boot image (check Wikipedia on "initrd" if you need some more details/phrasing). Also possibly good references are post on our site [mentioning initrd](/search?q=initrd) :)

Comment: So if i erase all data and flash firmware using adb, everything else will be regenerated during boot tme? do android drivers work properly after flashing?

Comment: @Izzy Given that I had little prior knowledge of `initrd`, I feel you're more suited for answering this, especially after seeing [this previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134101/editing-root-files/134104#134104) of yours - your call.

Comment: @AndyYan Done. Just didn't want to steal your initiative :)

Comment: @Izzy No prob - a chance for myself to learn too.

Answer (score 1):

The root file system (`/`) and the files therein (plus several more in some sub-directories) are created at boot time from the so-called [InitRd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) ("initial RAM disk", or "boot image").

Plus, there are some special "directories" which hold not really "files" but map system information (there's a Unix maxime saying "everything is a file"); in a terminal (or from `adb shell`) run the command `mount`, and you see some special file systems like [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) and [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs): the former holds system information, the latter temporary stuff.

As those are created by InitRd, you don't need to worry about them being lost when flashing a new ROM: they weren't really there, and the boot image from the new ROM will take care of creating them properly as well.

For further details, please also refer to [these posts](/search?q=initrd) on our site.