# Why if I delete a file or folder from root (/) it comes back when I reboot?

Tags: file-system, mount, partitions

I have a rooted Samsung S4 mini(Android 4.4.4), I noted that there are certain files/folders(for example /dev) that when I delete them they come back when I reboot the phone. Why? Is it possible to delete them permanently?

I know that this is very risky and may brick my phone, but:

1. I'm very curious about this.
2. It is my guinea pig device.
3. I can re-flash it(I did it several times ;-)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any changes to files in root directory (/) are gone after reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56888/any-changes-to-files-in-root-directory-are-gone-after-reboot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [GiantTree explained parts of the folder structure](/a/175418/16575), he missed one "mount point": `/` aka "the root file system". This is created on boot, from contents of the **"boot image"** – which is a so-called "initial RAM disk" or, in short, **[Initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd).** As it's created from the very same source at each boot, you can delete the stuff as often as you want – it will always return (until you "accidentally" delete that boot image itself – and are lost if you don't have a backup). Only after that, the other file systems are mounted – which GiantTree listed a few examples from (more details e.g. in [my answer here](/a/46934/16575)).

---

Let me add an urgent warning: Never touch what you don't know what it's for (delete the wrong thing, and your device no longer starts up). Always create a good [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) (see e.g. [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid)) before you start "playing" with system files. Far too many people end up here with having things deleted and not being able to get them back: without a proper backup, you can have a very hard time (especially with an exotic device that has no ROMs for download anywhere).

Comment: You are right, I missed `rootfs`. I had this feeling that I missed something but I wasn't sure how the root actually behaves. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @GiantTree Anytime! We [had that initrd stuff before](/search?q=initrd+user%3A16575) – so additional details can be found in those other posts (skip the "user" part to double the number :)

Answer (score 1):

Android is based on Linux, so it inherits much of the folder structure.

Using the command `mount`, you can find out what partitions are mounted in Android and what their respective types are.
I will go over a few important ones.

- `/cache`: This directory hold the *cache* partition. Deleting it won't do much bad, the cache just needs to be rebuild.
- `/data`: This holds your *data* partition. Deleting it (or anything within in) might result in errors, apps crashing or general loss of data.
- `/system`: This holds your *system* partition. Deleting it or anything within it (if possible) might result in your device being incapable to boot successfully.
- `/dev`: This holds device information. It is created upon boot and can be thought of as a *volatile* or *virtual* partition. Files there are usually not removable and not saved.
- `/efs`: This partition holds your IMEI and other info. While it shouldn't be writable, some circumstances might lead to it being cleared. Your IMEI will then be reset to 0 and you can't connect to any mobile network. BEWARE WHEN DOING ANYTHING WITH THIS PARTITION.
- `/proc`: This partition holds *process* information and is, like `/dev`, recreated on boot. Here, however, some files are removable and might lead to processes crashing or locking up. There is no need to do anything in here.