# hostapd reappears after deletion or renaming

Tags: wifi-hotspot, system, hostapd

Device: T-Mobile "Revvlry" branded version of the Motorola G7+.

ROM: https://doc.e.foundation/devices/lake, which shows up in the phone settings as Android 10.

Rooted: Yes. I'm using Termux which has superuser rights in Magisk, and su gets me #.

[How do I disable the Mobile Hotspot feature?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/how-do-i-disable-the-mobile-hotspot-feature)

[I'm trying to disable hotspot but I can't find hostapd on android 9](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221231/im-trying-to-disable-hotspot-but-i-cant-find-hostapd-on-android-9)

Following the instructions in these two questions, I found hostapd in /vendor/bin/hw and attempted to rename or remove it. It disappears momentarily the first time I list the files after deleting, but if I exit the terminal and then return and list again it reappears. Same with renaming, it appears under the new name and then reverts. The remount step also causes hostapd to reappear even though it gives an error -  "mount: '/dev/block/dm-0'->'/vendor': I/0 error".

[Any changes to files in root directory (/) are gone after reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56888/any-changes-to-files-in-root-directory-are-gone-after-reboot)

[Why if I delete a file or folder from root (/) it comes back when I reboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175409/why-if-i-delete-a-file-or-folder-from-root-it-comes-back-when-i-reboot)

I've found these answers which explain how Android will restore system files in root from a boot image, but I did not need to reboot my device to make hostapd reappear. Also, the first question I linked says that they were able to delete/rename hostapd successfully.

Comment: It might help to know what hostapd does and whey yo need it gone.

Comment: @rohitgupta Deleting or moving hostapd disables the mobile hotspot functionality. This is covered in detail in the two questions I linked.