# Understanding the Android boot

Tags: recovery-mode, boot

I really want to run pure Linux on my Android-based device (please, no `chroot`, etc. suggestions), and I want to fully understand how my device boots, from the bootloader as far as the `init` system. I'm not interested in any of the Android components that run after `init`.

I'm trying to dig into the *recovery* and *boot* partitions, without success. I figured out `boot.img`, but I can't open `recovery.img`.

What do you suggest me to read?

Also, I saw that there is a second kernel inside `recovery.img`. Is that right? If yes, what happens? When is the real kernel loaded?

Comment: Following up to the [boot tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot/info), you will find your answer here: [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575)

Comment: I think I am familiar with these. Also everrything that happens after the init stage, is not of interest to me (all the strange java magic)

Comment: OK, but everything from your question going beyond that is rather off-topic here: this site is for *end users* and their issues with Android, not for *development related issues* (altering the RAM-disk and creating custom ROMs definitely belongs to the latter, per our definition). These things are much better discussed at sites like XDA, or other specialized developer forums. See also: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) Good luck!