# What/How quick reboot works?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, reboot, accessibility, quick-settings

On my Android 4.2.2 (Micromax Canvas A74), From **System settings >Accessibility**, there is option for enabling  **"Quick Reboot"** as follows:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

So How it differs from normal reboot? Or what enabling this exactly work?

Comment: I do not see this Accessibility option on my Samsung S3, which uses TouchWiz. What phone and Launcher is this?

Comment: @wbogacz Edited question with phone model, using default launcher and I don't think/believe that launcher affect system-settings!

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen this option built-in, but there are several apps/widgets on the Playstore offering a "quick boot" as well. The term is a little misleading, as it's usually not a boot at all.

For some background information, let me first refer to my answer on [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575). Quick-reboot usually kills everything down to the "system server", so Zygote has to start it anew. As Zygote is the parent to all apps, basically the "Android-part" of the system is completely reloaded – while the underlying "Linux-part" keeps running.

From the users' point of view, this looks like a "quick reboot": the graphical interface (all apps, including the home screen) disappear, and then the system comes up again exactly like after a "boot". But during this process, the first 4 steps of a "real boot" (as outlined in the linked question) were skipped.

I'm not 100% sure if the "quick boot" option you are seeing there is the same, but it's pretty likely. Because, if it were a "full boot, just quicker" – then why shouldn't that be used in the first place?

Comment: And also you should once per week do a normal (slow:-)) reboot to "refresh" your device.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab only if necessary. If everything works normally, why reboot? I usually don't boot more often than once a month, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different quick boot compared to the other answers.

Qualcomm and MediaTek devices have this feature and it basically another name for Hibernation mode. When enabled, powering off the device hibernates instead of fully shutting down. (In turn making boot faster)

Comment: There is no hibernation mode in Android. So, what are you referring to?

Comment: There's none normally but that's what QuickBoot adds. Here's a video of how it works in the OnePlus One (works the same here) https://youtu.be/hiKTL-bg9yk

Comment: That is not hibernation. All that mode does is to put the device into airplane mode, lock the screen, send the device to normal sleep mode and make sure that the device doesn't wake up unless the power button is long pressed. It is not hibernation, neither literally nor technically. You can still launch apps using adb or access device's storage - when device is powered off using this quickboot mode. My findings are based on Android Lollipop.

Comment: On the 3 devices I have used it on, it didn't do that. You couldn't access the device. It actually did shut off but it can only be done on certain hardware as its a feature of the SoC. Yes hibernation may have not been the best wording, but it is a hardware specific low power mode which is what hibernation accomplishs just in a different way.

Answer (score -2):

I have two Blu Phone, the Dash 5.0 with 4.4.2, and a 5.0 HD also 4.4.2. The build numbers are different though. The HD has the quick boot option. The Dash does not. Before I enabled the quick boot the boots times were the same about 35 secs. But now with it enabled, the HD boots in 14 seconds. So it does what it says and does not seem to work any differently after booting.

Comment: I think we understand the meaning of "quick" literally, but how/why does it work? OP specifically asked that questions.