# How to hard brick an android phone (Galaxy Nexus)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, boot, fastboot, unbricking

I'm trying to figure out whether or not I managed to brick my android phone, a Galaxy Nexus*.

Using ClockworkMod Recovery, I pretty much erased everything I could find (`/data`, `/cache`, `/factory`, `/system`, `/boot`, `/sbl`, `/xloader`). If I reboot now, will I still be able to boot into ClockworkMod? Specifically, `/recovery` is not on said list.

I am trying to find information on how the boot process works, but it is very hard to discover around the web among all the end-user specific noise. As far as I understand it, there is a stage-one bootloader in an actual ROM (emphasis on read-only), but I do not know whether the fastboot-functionality is contained in it.

Hypothetically speaking, if I were (able) to zero every block of the internal SD-card sans the read-only ROM, would that brick the device?

To my knowledge, as long as I can still get into fastboot, the device is not bricked? If all this fails, can I use special hardware to restore it?

*: I should note it is currently powered on and has loaded the ClockworkMod Recovery. I believe I could get it back to working order, but I really want to find the minimum amount of software I can get away with.

Comment: ....... Why? Alright, you said why, but still..... I have never heard of intentional bricking. If you can't restore it, what are you going to do?

Comment: As it says in the text, I'm not intentionally bricking it; I just erased a bunch of things and am now wondering whether or not that did *actually* brick it. -- The whole "can I brick it?" question is just me trying to figure out things from the other end.

Comment: Ok, but (assuming you do brick it) this is an intentional brick. Have you tried rebooting it?

Comment: @DanB I have not rebooted it yet, since I am still inside the RecoveryMod, where it should be fairly easy to fix things. If it does turn out to be a brick, rebooting would close my door back in, so to speak.

Comment: Fair point, but it would be the only way to check :( I just looked at my recovery, and found I had stopped the wipe of anything :)

Comment: Hello , "hard bricking" describes a completly unfunctional phone. If you can still power it on then it is not hard bricked. Hardbricking a phone is rare these days but when android modding was started it was a real fear. Like you said, if you can access the fastboot, the device is not bricked. Users often use the term "hard bricked" when their device is not booting up to android anymore. But as long as they can access the recovery or the fastboot option the correct term to use is softbrick. I Don't think that these partitions you have erased will brick your device, but I never had a nexus.

Comment: Hi, i was just curious about what you're working on. If your block/patition layout is like my device then dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/mmcblk0 will brick your device hard in a few minutes.

Comment: "all the end-user specific noise": Uh-oh. I hope you are aware that this here is a site dedicated to those "noisy end-users" :) Taking a look into our [boot tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot/info) will lead you to [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575). Isn't that what you are looking for? It should be pretty obvious that by wiping `/boot` the device no longer "boots" (not even to recovery). The `fastboot` mode might still work (fail-safe for re-flashing), though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, your device is not that hard bricked, that you can't boot into the bootloader (fastboot mode). so at every time you should be able to install a custom recovery via `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`. if you are in recovery mode with a working recovery, you can do a factory reset (reflash the system, root,... partitions from a protected image) and reboot your device. alternatively you can do a factory reset in fastboot mode.

note: if you erased **everything**, your recovery will freeze like if you pull off the hard drive from a running Linux. also there are partitions, you are never able to flash, as example the RADIO partition, fastboot or the one, containing the factory reset data. (RADIO partitions contains fine tuned configuration and management of the gprs, lte,... modem)

Comment: What's most interesting to me now is, if I powered off now without loading another image, would I still be able to boot into ClockworkMod? From how I understand your answer that should be possible. Also, is it impossible to ruin fastboot?

Comment: as I said, it should not be possible to ruin fastboot (if you unlocked the device via the proprietary way, the way, the hardware provider expected from you).

Comment: Alright, I rebooted and had to take out the battery afterwards (stuck with the Google Logo). Holding down VolUp+VolDown while powering on got me into the menu to select Recovery and my ClockwordMod is working.