# What makes the android boot sequence different from Windows boot sequence?

Tags: security, boot, operating-system

I've just studied the Windows boot process (theoretically) and now I want to compare the Android's boot sequence with the Windows boot sequence. One point I've found is that in Windows there is BIOS and in android there is BOOT ROM that does the same task. Can you please help me to get more differences? Also which is more secure in terms of boot process and why?

Comment: See [Android device load process](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205140/218526) and [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526) and [Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526) and [BOOT PROCESS: ANDROID vs. LINUX](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux.3785254/). All answers cover Android vs. PC (Linux or Windows) scenario.

Comment: On Windows BIOS/UEFI is a standardized technology. On Android the lower boot process is not standardized at all.

Comment: Robert, I think you did not understand my question. Actually, I'm searching for the difference between Android's boot sequence and Window's boot sequence. Also, I'm concerned about the security that which has a more secure boot sequence?